# how to get UserController.CreateUser(userinfo) procedure in dnn?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have 2 DNN sites. I need to synchronize user table while registering user in one. 
ie. if a user register at site 1, that user will be available in site 2.
 So I need to use the query behind

> UserController.CreateUser(userInfo).

Comment: I am getting an issue with simultaneously registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create entries in `UserProtal` table, so for example, you have two portals with id 0 and 1. If user registers to portal 0, `UserController.CreateUser` will create entry in `UserPortal` table with portal 0 and new userid. Once user is created, you have to create same kind of entry for portal 1 and new userid in same table.

Let me know if you have any other question on this

Comment: i have synchronize these tables `Users,Membership,UserPortals,UserProfile,UserRoles`.i need to synchronize dnn 4 to dnn 5.but in membership table the same password have different encoding format.so how to resolver this problem?